# Linux Can't Detect Some Hard Drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, zfs, hba

I have a dell R820 with an LSI 9211-8i HBA installed. I connected one hard drive, a dell with model number `HUC101890CSS204`, and installed ubuntu 18.04 onto it from a usb stick.

I then added 3 HGST hard drives, model number `HUC109090CSS600`. All 4 hard drives are connected to the computer via the HBA.

According to [this pdf](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/IT-SAS-Gen2.5CompatibilityList), the HGST drives should be compatible with the HBA.

However, while the HBA can detect all four drives from within its BIOS, and some terminal commands can detect all four drives, I can only mount and access the dell drive.

Output from `lsblk` (sda2 is the dell drive):

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  86.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop1    7:1    0  96.6M  1 loop /snap/core/9804
sda      8:0    0 838.4G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 838.4G  0 part /
```

Output from `ls -al /dev/disk/by-path`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 160 Sep  3 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Sep  3 23:19 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy0-lun-0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy1-lun-0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Sep  3 23:19 pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0 -> ../../sdd
```

Output from `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 86.6 MiB, 90759168 bytes, 177264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 96.6 MiB, 101318656 bytes, 197888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 838.4 GiB, 900185481216 bytes, 1758174768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F30A7AE2-560F-41C1-A388-BFE2D7C3C5A8

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 1758171135 1758167040 838.4G Linux filesystem
```

Output from `lsscsi`:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    HGST     HUC101890CSS204  FE10  /dev/sda 
[0:0:1:0]    disk    NETAPP   X423_HCOBE900A10 NA01  /dev/sdb 
[0:0:2:0]    disk    NETAPP   X423_HCOBE900A10 NA01  /dev/sdc 
[0:0:3:0]    disk    NETAPP   X423_HCOBE900A10 NA01  /dev/sdd
```

Output from `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/newhd`:

```
mount: /media/newhd: can't read superblock on /dev/sdb.
```

I'm pretty new to this sort of thing, so I'm at a loss. What diagnostics/tools are necessary to access the three additional hard drives?

Thanks.

Comment: Check `dmesg` output for these drives.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the advice. After grepping the output from `dmesg` for the different drive names, I found errors that the drives had 520-byte byte sectors, which is the source of the issue. I didn't think to check that since according to the PDF I linked above, these drives should be 512 bytes.

Comment: Those disks aren't the model you seem to think they are. They are the model listed in `lsscsi`. See [here](https://serverfault.com/q/1025239/126632) for further information.

Comment: Btw usually you mount a partition not the whole disk, like `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newhd`

Comment: You can also check the solution in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404405/how-to-detect-new-hard-disk-attached-without-rebooting